# Two Linear Algebra questions - Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

These two are both very similar. The first is -Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$. Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation. Suppose that $T$ is one-to-one. Show that there is a linear transformation $L:W\to V$ such that $LT=1v$? 
 ----> So far, I have, If $T:V\to W$ then $B_v =\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $B_w=\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ is basis for $W$. where $v=a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n$ and $T(v)=b_1w_1+\dots+b_mw_m$. confused where to go from there?

The second question is Let $T:V\to W$ and $L:W\to V$ be a linear transformation. Show 1.) $T$ is injective if $LT=1v$ and 2.) $T$ is surjective if $TL=1w$
For this one, all i know is that you have to show that $L$ is unique and that $L$ is linear.

Im really bad at linear transformations, so I could really use the guidance. Thanks!

Comment: This can help: http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/invertible-linear-transformations-pt-ii/
(Note that the result is true for set-functions. You just need to check that the left-invese, defined as in the link, is indeed also linear transformation in your case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a **left** inverse, usually called a *retraction.*  (Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses).)

We need to define $L:W \to V$.  For any $w$ in the image of $T$, so there is a $v \in V$ with $T(v) = w$, we can *define* $L(w) = v$.  Why does that make sense?  The transformation *T* is one-to-one, so the $v$ that we're using is unique.

What to do about $L(w)$ for $w \notin \operatorname{Im} T$?  Hint:  every $w = w_0 + w_1$ for some $w_0 \in \operatorname{Im} T$.

Comment: Yes first part makes sense, but what does ImT mean? Isomorphism T?

Comment: Im just not familiar with the Id_y in the link?

Comment: Im T means "the image of T," which is the set of outputs of the function.

Comment: Id_Y just means the identity function on Y.  That is the function whose output is the same as input:  Id_Y (y) = y for all y in Y.

Comment: Im kinda confused on the last part there. However, if in fact T is one-to-one. The the nullity(T)=0 correct? So

Comment: we can define L to be T inverse?

Comment: Only _invertible_ transformations have inverses.  Consider, for example, the one-to-one linear trans. T: R --> R^2, T(t) = (2t, 3t).  It cannot have an inverse.  (The matrix in the standard bases is not square!)

Comment: Oh yes of course. But we know that T is one-to-one so then it is also invertible (invertible matrix theorem)?